# Delphi Devexpress TcxGrid Scroll Events

Tags: delphi, devexpress, tcxgrid

I am using the cxGrid component with a TcxGridTableView. I need to get the offset distance of the scroll bar. I wonder there are scroll events that I can use to get this information?

I'm looking for how much pixels were scrolled because I want to display something like a rule of pixels from the left position of the grid above it, and i have to count the pixels "hidden", shifted by the scroll.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may get an answer quicker if you search the devexpress website, and/or ask on their forums.

Comment: Thank you, I've already posted there too.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the grid has some sort of index property that specifies the rownumber of the top visible row in the grid. This property can be read and set. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I guess not. I'm looking for how much pixels were scrolled because I want to display something like a rule of pixels from the left position of the grid above it, and i have to count the pixels "hidden" by the scroll.

Sorry if I gave a bad description, but english isn't my native language.

Thanks.

Comment: @diogo: On StackOverflow you can edit your question to provide these additional details.

Comment: Ok, I thought you might be looking for the record-position. Maybe if you multiply the index by the row height you'll get what yo need?